# AndEngine - move object

Tags: android, andengine

I have two buttons on the screen and a player object. The first button must move the player to the left and the second to the right, but the player doesn't move smoothly. How I can make the player to move smoothly?

```
ButtonSprite rightButton = new ButtonSprite(360,700,this.resourceManager.RightButtonRegion,this.vertexManager)
{
    @Override
    public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY)
    {
        player.MoveRight();
        return super.onAreaTouched(pSceneTouchEvent, pTouchAreaLocalX, pTouchAreaLocalY);
    }
};

ButtonSprite leftButton = new ButtonSprite(50,700,this.resourceManager.LeftButtonRegion,this.vertexManager)
{
    @Override
    public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY)
    {
        player.MoveLeft();
        return super.onAreaTouched(pSceneTouchEvent, pTouchAreaLocalX, pTouchAreaLocalY);
    }
};

public class Player extends Sprite
{
    ...

    public void MoveLeft()
    {
        float x = this.body.getPosition().x -0.2f;
        float y =  this.body.getPosition().y;
        this.body.setTransform(x,y,0);
    }

    public void MoveRight() 
    {
        float x = this.body.getPosition().x + 0.2f;
        float y =  this.body.getPosition().y;
        this.body.setTransform(x, y, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your MoveLeft method you are adding a pre-fixed value, this will not scale to frame rate.

You should set a flag like "movingLeft = true" at this method, and at your processLogics you should move the position based on framerate.